# Azure AWS Db Connection

Tags: sql-server, azure, amazon-web-services, database-connection

I’m having a very specific issue with Azure and I couldn’t find any solution on the web.

So, we are little by little migrating our client’s infrastructure to Azure and we are starting with our Workers (webjobs).
These webjobs need to consume data present on a AWS SQL Server instance.
We already have checked that the App Service Plan’s Outbound IPs are whitelisted and that the SQL server is listening on TCP port 1433.

An evidence of that is the fact that we are able to communicate with the SQL Server instance through the Azure Debug Console:
[image]

But when we run the WebApp, the worker cannot find and connect to the same DB:
[image]

Does anyone have a clue of how I can solve this issue? It would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as you demonstrated by the first image, the SQL Server instance is configured correctly.
The worker Outbound IP address is definetely the same as the App Service Plan's machine.

Based on that, can you then please check if the Connection string you are setting have 'tcp:' before the IP Address?
Sometimes you need to force it, otherwise IIS can choose other ways to connect to your SQL server (like UDP for instance).